# Why are Oracle time zones wrong?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, timezone, timezone-offset

Why does Oracle have the wrong time zones? Chicago is off by an hour, Denver is off by an hour, etc.

The Linux server's time as well as Oracle's sessiontimezone and dbtimezone are correct.

Oracle's current_date does differ from sysdate by an hour. They should be the same.

```
SELECT tzabbrev, SUBSTR(tz_offset(tzname), 1, 6), tzname FROM v$timezone_names tz WHERE tzname = 'America/Denver';
LMT -07:00  America/Denver
MST -07:00  America/Denver
MWT -07:00  America/Denver
MDT -07:00  America/Denver
```

These should all be **-06:00**!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF9 TZH:TZM';

SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
       SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver'
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SYSTIMESTAMPATTIMEZONE'UTC' | SYSTIMESTAMPATTIMEZONE'AMERICA/DENVER' |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-06-29 22:09:27.786125000 +00:00 | 2021-06-29 16:09:27.786125000 -06:00 |

If you do:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'America/Denver';
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output on db<>fiddle (which is in the UK and currently on UTC+1):

> | SYSTIMESTAMP | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-06-29 23:09:27.788275000 +01:00 | 2021-06-29 16:09:27.788278000 -06:00 |

I assume that your server time zone is set to UTC-7 and your session time zone is set to America/Denver (UTC-6) and you are using `SYSTIMESTAMP` which is getting the server time rather than the session time which `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` would return.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c3eafd676ac204638895d6ee9d8d4dd1)*

Comment: Unfortunately not. Both servers have the same time. `$date
Tue Jun 29 16:24:40 MDT 2021`
Current_date differs between the two systems. The main strangeness is that all the time zone offsets are wrong on server2.

Answer (score 1):

Your DB version is out-of-date if you are still on 11g.

You can check how out of date your timezone file is

SELECT * FROM v$timezone_file;

You should look into upgrading, but may have to dust off manuals for doing that in 11g.

https://oracle-blog.com/upgrade-database-timezone-file-in-oracle-19c-upgrade/

Comment: Agreed, we have an upgrade plan in place but it will take a while for this database.

Comment: However, all other databases have the right TZ offsets, including Oracle 11. Even with the oldest timezone files, there was no time when every major city in the U.S. (that I checked) was off by an hour in the middle of summer.

Answer (score 1):

Elimiate any issue with the 'current' time or with sneaky local replacements of the TZOFFSET. Check for a date that should be -6:00 and another that should be -7:00. Repeat for different years. I suspect that it doesn't switch between March 7th and 8th 2020, or Match 13th/14th 2021. There's an outside chance that the OS is supplying Oracle with an incorrect clock time (eg a UK time rather than UTC time)

```
with
    x as
        (select timestamp '2020-07-01 13:00:00 America/Denver' denver_time
        from dual)
select to_char(denver_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI TZH:TZM') denver_time,
         to_char(denver_time at time zone 'UTC','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI TZH:TZM') utc_time,
         to_char(denver_time at time zone dbtimezone,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI TZH:TZM') db_time,
     dbtimezone, sessiontimezone
from x;

with
    x as
        (select timestamp '2020-03-01 13:00:00 America/Denver' denver_time
        from dual)
select to_char(denver_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI TZH:TZM') denver_time,
         to_char(denver_time at time zone 'UTC','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI TZH:TZM') utc_time,
         to_char(denver_time at time zone dbtimezone,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI TZH:TZM') db_time,
         dbtimezone, sessiontimezone
from x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Daylight savings time?  SessionTimeZone comes from the session settings rather than the database timezone settings.

Comment: The two servers do have different dbtimezones (one UTC, one Denver time), but I don't understand how that would affect the UTC offset for today when the next daylight savings change is in November.
Man, I dislike time zones in general.